# $geoWithin query form mongodb to mongoose statement

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Have this query from mongodb:

```
 db.location.find(
 {loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ 9, 9], 
 radius ] } }, action:1 })
 .limit(10)
 .skip(1, function(err,   result) {
    console.dir(result);
 });
```

How to translate it to mongoose statement with using geoWithin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well some thing like this:

```
 LocationModel.where('loc').within({ center: [ your_lat, your_lng], radius: your_radius, unique: true, spherical: true }).where('action').equals(your_action).skip(your_skip).limit(10).exec(
    function(err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

befor of course need create LocationModel and LocationSchema,
i hope it's can help.